# How to add OPTIONS request before main request in axios

Tags: javascript, cors, axios

**I want to send OPTIONS request before main request for solve CORS problem.**
How to solve this problem from client side?

I used a browser extension for solve problem. And it worked. But I don't want to use an extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related

And here's my code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const service = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://sub.domain.com/api/",
    timeout: 10000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'auth'
    }
})


export default class API {
    static getData () {
        return service.get('get-data')
    }
}

=====

API.getData()
```

Comment: Your existing code **already** sends a preflight OPTIONS request (you've set the `Content-Type` to JSON which is one of the triggers for it).

Comment: It sounds like your actual problem is that the service you are making the request to doesn't give you permission in the response to the preflight OPTIONS request. If so, then you would get an error message, and you should be quoting it and asking about that.

Comment: :D what @Quentin mentioned here is right :) and it's the same thing in my answer which someone downvoted

Answer (score 0):

A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser, when needed. In normal cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such requests themselves.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

so you don't need to do it by yourself as long as you are doing the request from your browser if the API server you are calling doesn't allow your localhost domain, you need to change the domain in your browser to be allowed domain 
as an example if the server responding to  options  by headers that allow access from www.xyz.com only 
you can edit etc/hosts file in your machine to make it point to localhost

```
127.0.0.1       localhost www.xyz.com
```

then you can open the code in the browser using  www.xyz.com  and now the access will be allowed